# Sending message to c2dm with oauth 2 and getting 401

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

I have a version of my app using c2dm from google without oauth authentication and it works fine. But I want to migrate to oauth 2. I'm have a problem when tying to send a message, I keep getting 401 unauthorized. 
I created a Service Account to get the ClientID, email address and the private Key.I already sign up for c2dm (twice), refreshed multiple times the authentication token and I'm using the same email in both server and device. Does anyone have some idea why this is happening?

```
public static String getToken() {

    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();        

    String clientId = "****.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    String pkcs12Repo = "*****privatekey.p12";
    String scope = "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm";      

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(clientId)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(pkcs12Repo))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(scope)
        .build();

        credential.refreshToken();
        String token = credential.getAccessToken();
        return token;
}

public static int sendMessage(String auth_token, String registrationId, String message) {

        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        postDataBuilder.append("registration_id").append("=").append(registrationId);
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("collapse_key").append("=").append("0");
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8"));

        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL("https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new CustomizedHostnameVerifier());
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth_token);

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        return responseCode;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

C2DM doesn't support OAuth2 authentication.  The ClientLogin AuthToken is your only supported method at this time.

Comment: a lot of people have already successfully used C2DM with OAuth2. Google recently changed this service to incorporate OAuth2.0 and deprecated the ClientLogin AuthToken.